# How to know which Brahmin sub-caste is real and which one is fake?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins

All Brahmin sub-castes call one another fake brahmins and themselves to be the real one. So, How to know which one is real and which one is fake ?

Comment: never heard of someone calling other subcaste fake, where did you get this info? And what is meant by subcaste? like kanyakubj etc? or mishr, sharma etc